# Possible to change LED light color when Junction box does not have a switch?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting

Is it possible to switch these lights (pictures attached) to Daylight White color when junction box does not have the switch on it?

[image]

[image]

(Context : Older owners have installed these lights in the entire house)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to change the color of these lights is to replace them. Unlike *some* LED lights which are switchable (depending on the type, anything from a physical switch on the fixture or bulb to a remote "smart" WiFi configuration), these are designed to have only one color - *Warm White 3000K*. A dimmer will let you adjust the brightness but not the color.

Comment: A dimmer *may* let you adjust...

Comment: @Huesmann It says Triac dimmable